# Is it possible for hamiltonian systems to have asymptotically stable rest points?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-theory

Is it possible for hamiltonian (dynamical) systems to have asymptotically stable rest points? By Liouville's theorem I got that for symplectic hamiltonian systems only Lyapunov stability is allowed.

My knowledge about symplectic manifolds is however limited and my question would be if it is possible for "non symplectic" hamiltonian (dynamical) systems to exist and to have asymptotically stable rest points.

Comment: Please tell more about these "'non-symplectic' Hamiltonian systems". $\dot q=H_p,\,\dot p=-H_q$ is per construction symplectic for $\omega=\sum_i dp_i\wedge dq_i$.

Comment: @LutzL: It's not really clear, but maybe it's supposed to refer to Hamiltonian systems on Poisson manifolds (as opposed to symplectic manifolds)?